# Spark : Named_struct requires at least one argument

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am mapping a Dataset of Row to a Dataset of a custom class.

```
Dataset<Row> rows= sparkSession.read().orc(path);
Dataset<customClass> dataset =
  rows.map(I'm parsing row to map it to customClass, 
    Encoders.bean(customClass.class));
```

And I am getting this AnalysisException:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'named_struct()' due to data type mismatch: input to function named_struct requires at least one argument;

I am using Spark 2.3.0 and am encoding my custom class using javaBeans.

I checked whether the schema was effectivly inferred by Encoders and it is the case. So, technically, the map operation should work.

Has anyone ever faced this exception message ? What does the named_struct function do ? I found no relevant information related to Spark ...

```
root
 |-- field1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- field4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field5: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field6: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field61: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field62: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field63: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field64: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field7: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field8: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field9: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field91: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: struct
 |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field911: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field912: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field913: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: struct
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- field9131: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- field9131: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field914: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field915: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field11: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field111: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: struct
 |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- field1111: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field1112: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field12: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- field13: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field131: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- field132: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- field14: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field141: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How do you _"I'm parsing row to map it to customClass"_. I'm still expecting to spot something that would be similar to `named_struct`. What are the fields of your `customClass`?

Comment: customClass has the following fields :
String,Integer, Double, Boolean and Enumeration. In addition to that, it has other classes as fields. Let A, B, C, D, E be thoses classes : 
A has a Map<B,C>.
B has only a String.
C has String,Integer, Double, Enumeration and a Map<Integer,Double>.
D has String, Double and Integer.
E has a Map<Integer,Double>.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the logical query plan, e.g. `q.explain(true)`? Could you add the output of `System.out.println(Encoders.bean(customClass.class))` too? Can you remove all uses of `Map` in your `customClass` and start over (just to test it could give a better result with no maps as they are partially supported)?

Comment: I am unable to get the logical query plan, since program is crashing when I'm creating my `Dataset<customClass>`. I think the problem is related to `Maps` : on the `customClass` schema, keys to `Maps` are `struct` and don't have values linked to them. Maybe that's why I am having this problem.

Comment: I've seen comments in the code to say that [map support is in progress](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L137) and that's why I asked to see if the issue goes away with no map.

Comment: I tried to swith keys in `Maps` to supported classes (`Integer` and `String`). Unfortunatly, it didn't work. I am going to change the whole model and remove `Maps` from it. I'll let you know how it ends up.

Comment: I finally found why I had this `named_struct` error : One of the fields I was using was declared `final`, which means it didn't have a setter. This violates the `JavaBean` contract.

Comment: Excellent! Care to make this comment an answer and to accept it afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found why I had this `named_struct` error : One of the fields I was using was declared `final`, which means it didn't have a setter. This violates the `JavaBean` contract.

Comment: Yes, sadly in spark with java we have to use mutable bean :(